# How to design a Tab which shows content Vertically

Tags: wpf

I have to design a tab control. Tab item header should be shown verically.

Comment: Questions cant be 'urgent'. You cant say peole to view your question First and forget others.

Comment: Besides every question on SO is urgent. Let's face it, you only ask when it's your last resort.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you describe the ways you investigated already, which can be a basis for somebody to help you.

Comment: -1 There is no question here, just a spec for work that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you the way to make this. Get a copy of the ControlTemplate of TabControl. You can get it **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx)** if you aren't using Expression Blend to edit.

```
 <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TabPanel 
        Name="HeaderPanel"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Panel.ZIndex="1" 
        Margin="0,0,4,-1" 
        IsItemsHost="True"
        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
        Background="Transparent" />
```

You can see the below 2-row grid and a TabPanel as the Header panel. This is why the default TabControl has its headerpanel(Tabs) sits on the top(first row). You can change this rows to columns and replace the TabPanel with a StackPanel or something with a vertical orientation will do the trick.